# Node.js - Callback is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to retrieve a var hash to use it in another module. But I have a problem with callback. I have the error "callback is not a function". I use callback because my variable hash is undefined, so I guess it's a problem of asynchronous.

**hash.js**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var algorithm = 'sha256';

var hash = function(filename, callback){
  var shasum = crypto.createHash(algorithm);
  var s = fs.ReadStream(filename);

  s.on('data', function(data) {
    shasum.update(data)
  })
  s.on('end', function() {
    var hash = shasum.digest('hex')
    callback(hash);
  })
}

exports.hash = hash;
```

**app.js**

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('userfile'), function(req, res){ 

  res.cookie('filename', req.file.originalname);
  res.cookie('filesize', req.file.size);
  var filename = __dirname +'/'+ req.file.path;
  console.log(hash.hash(filename))

  //res.cookie('hash', hash.hash(filename)); 
  res.redirect('/hash')
})
```

Comment: You are defining your hash function with 2 params but only call it with one: `hash.hash(filename)`.

Comment: then, how can i change it?

Comment: `hash.hash(filename, function(hashResult) { console.log(hashResult)})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `hash()` function is defined with this signature:

```
var hash = function(filename, callback)
```

That means you need to pass it BOTH a filename and a callback.  But, you are passing it only a filename:

```
console.log(hash.hash(filename))
```

As you can see in the implementation, the callback is not optional and is the only way to actually get the result like this:

```
hash.hash(filename, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: @Lock - Since it looks like you may be new here, if this answers your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here on stackoverflow for following the proper procedure.